# I need a book which/that(?) is cheap enough, but in which/that(?) there are cute photos

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns

On the one hand the clauses are restrictive, on the other hand, there is a preposition in the second case, So, it seems the correct version is "I need a book that is cheap enough, but  in which there are cute photos", but this sounds awful.

So, what is the correct choice?

Comment: I need a cheap book with cute pictures

Comment: No, this is a *different* sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the sentence is

> I need a book that is cheap enough, but in which there are cute photos.

and you are also correct that it is verbose, the suggested alternative

> I need a cheap book with cute pictures.
>   I need an affordable book with pictures.
>   I need an inexpensive book with pictures.

might be better.

Comment: In the sentece that I'm really trying  to formulate instead of just "cheap" and "cute pictures" huge phrases stand, so the brief version is not an option

Comment: It's shorter and more direct, but a  "cheap book" [= economical] does not carry the same meaning as "a book that is cheap enough" [=affordable]

Comment: @Serguei  Why do you want to have huge phrases?

Comment: It takes  a rare talent to write academical texts in succint clear phrases. My command of English is definitely insufficient :(